# Coded UI - Add-ons

Tags: ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm using VS 2013 with CodedUI to automate UI tests on an application that is not built by my client (it's an implementation project). When inspecting the UI Control using inspect or coded UI, I see that the Automation ID keeps changing and I have no real way (beside position based) to capture my controls (the application is developed in Delphi).

So I'm wondering if there exist some library or add-ons (or something not even related to Coded UI and VS) that can help with this? For example some tools that can capture a screen shot of the control and then map it (the screenshot) to an Control Id that I will define and use that to automate?

Comment: Just deleted my answer, my apologies, I thought it was a web application..  it's be a really long time since I've done desktop development.. if you get desperate, you could get the handle to the container and walk the children until you find the correct control by inspecting the text (poor-man's Spy++).. that having been said, there's probably a tool that will do that for you..

Comment: Don`t worry thanks for trying, I actually found a clever way using a fairly new and popular tool called sikuli for UI automation, image based recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Wow....I was able to find a way to do what I need using sikuli (http://www.sikuli.org/) checkout this post. Ill actually try it out tomorrow. But I found on the web (link below) that it`s possible.

From Coded UI we can call the sikuli script like that:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"D:\Sikuli\ds.bat";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

(code from) https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/232233 , read this post guys!